# Custom API key to protect firebase function endpoints

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, api-key

I need a long-lived, API keys generator, to protect my API endpoints for authorized users only (those who have the API key).
So I think there's nothing built into Firebase that I can use out of the box.
I thought that I should generate a Firestore document each time a user signs up and requests an API
key.
Then I'll use the document ID as the API key, which I could validate in the Cloud Function.
Something like this:

```
const apiKey = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
const doc = await admin.firestore().collection('apiKeys').doc(apiKey).get();
if (doc.exists) {
  next();
}
```

So my questions are:

- Is that a good approach?
- Do you have other suggestions?
- Does it scale?

Comment: If your users sign up, they have credentials. Why don't they just log in? Why do you need API keys?

Comment: @ChrisG Because I'm building a specific service where the users are actually servers and I want them to just program the secret key (==API key) that I'll provide to them upon registration into their server logic, so it will be easier to communicate with my API.

Comment: Ok, so why not hardcode the login instead, and have them login first?

Comment: @ChrisG I want to make it as easy to use as it can be, so the only thing they will need to do, is to sign up to my service, then get the secret key and for each post request they make to my server they'll have to add the secret key as well, in order to get a response. Just like how you communicate with Firebase itself as a product owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you ensure that your users cannot get a list of your API keys, that sounds like a reasonable approach.

It will scale fine on pretty much any database, as all you'll need to do is check if a document with a given ID exists.